# Optimization MySQL for large table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Question concerning MySQL and optimization over large table. The MySQL server is running on a limited capacity server and we need to optimize it as much as possible.

We are sampling data at a rate of one measurement per second and we use that to draw graphs on a web application.

Currently all those data are inside a single table and we end up with hundreds of millions of data points.

We have several data source which all have two ids: One for the position and one for the source itself. We use both ids together to have a unique id and we don't use MySQL id to reduce the size of the data. We use the posix plus both id together as the table primary key and we use them to query the DB. Those ID are not generated by SQL.

Usually we plot graph using about 400 points in time segments and several source.

Question:
What would be the best optimization for such design ?

First question: Is it better to keep all the data inside a single table or split them into several table ? This has the disadvantage to complicate the code as we would have dynamic tables.

If it's better to keep them in a single table, is it a correct approach to use a primary key based on ids and posix ?

Is there some specific mysql optimization for such purpose ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, the best optimization for this situation would be having a [distributed database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database#Important_considerations). More specifically, I would apply the [horizontal partitioning method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29#Partitioning_methods) to this table you mention.

Roughly saying, this is a method to have your table divided into **fragments** according to some specific criteria, so that your queries don't have to process huge amount of data all at once. You can use this to process only relevant data for some specific query, or even to process all data using parallelism.

Allow me to not explain any further since I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want and need, and also because you could possibly do better reading about this matter at your own pace. Hope this helps by giving you a starting point, though.

Comment: From your short explanation I would say it seem to perfectly fit our needs, fragmentation whether by time or source. I'll get further reading into it.

Comment: Indeed, Fragmentation over timestamp have improved the query by a factor 8.

Comment: Splendid! So glad I could help!